# Cannot start Google Cloud's Datastream stream: "Fetch failed: An unexpected error occurred. Contact Google Support.."

Tags: google-cloud-platform

so I created a Datastream stream in GCP to replicate data from a Cloud PostgreSQL instance to Google Cloud Storage, and when it starts, I receive this error "Fetch failed: An unexpected error occurred. Contact Google Support..". However, all validation tests passed ok.

[image: Datastream stream validation tests ok]

Does anyone have a solution?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this kind of error is a generic `POSTGRES\_CDC\_FETCH\_FAILED` error when trying to create a new stream.

I would highly suggest to file a bug/feature request on this concern in this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/) once you created bug/feature request you can also track the progress on that created ticket on that link that I provided. However, there's no ETA for it.

You may also contact [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) to investigate your project and check in depth your datastream connection.

The Product team is currently investigating this bug.

Comment: Thank you. Some tables in our PostgreSQL database had row-level security enabled and disabling it fixed it.